# tcpdump merge possibility with dpi library

Tags: tcpdump, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

Does tcpdump can able to merge with any dpi library for deep paket flow analysis.

For example: I need skype protocol flow details and header details.

Comment: ya i tried wireshark.but it doesn't analyse deep protocols like skype,whatsapp etc.,Thats why i came to this idea.please suggest the possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

> ya i tried wireshark.but it doesn't analyse deep protocols like skype,whatsapp etc., please suggest the possible solutions.

For Skype: if the Skype dissector already in Wireshark doesn't dissect enough of the protocol, read [the document people reverse-engineering the undocumented Skype protocol wrote](https://github.com/matthiasbock/OpenSkype/wiki/Skype%27s-UDP-Format), and enhance that dissector to dissect more of the protocol.

For WhatsApp: add [this WhatsApp plugin](https://github.com/davidgfnet/wireshark-whatsapp) to Wireshark.

Comment: Thank you for your response harris. I need more deep protocols like xbox,viber and more application protocols. nDPI is an open source library anlaysing and detecting more deep protocols but it provides only  protocol and flow list.I need to sniff these protocols to view header and payload.Thats the main goal. whereas tcpdump sniffs common protocols and gives the details as i need.so is there any open tool to deep protocol sniff or is there any possibility to merge sniffer and deep packet capturer??..i hope you will understand my goal.i am expecting the possible solutions.

Comment: "deep", when used as an adjective for "packet capture" or "packet inspection", is a marketing term, and really means nothing.  Wireshark captures the full contents of packets and analyzes all protocols for which it has dissectors, with whatever detail the dissector supports.  Additional protocols can be added, and additional detail can be added to existing dissectors.  If it doesn't handle a particular protocol in enough detail, ***AND*** there's enough information to extend it to do so, it can be extended to do so.

Comment: yes i agree with you harris ,wireshark sniffs and captures full contents of a protocol.but wireshark doesn't support more protocols right.but my goal is to capture deep protocols and to sniff that for full content capture.i guess you could understand my query

Comment: "wireshark sniffs and captures full contents of a protocol.but wireshark doesn't support more protocols"  Then you'll need to extend it to support more protocols, if you want packet details for "full content".  Or you can write your *own* sniffer like Wireshark, but that's more work than just adding stuff to Wireshark.  If you're looking for a solution that *doesn't* involve doing work, you're probably not going to find it.

Comment: not like that.I analysed fully and then got the idea to merge the tcpdump and nDPI.The thing is that some of them having product like these deep packet sniffer.so I am asking some indepth hints to achieve this.if i am not having involvement.why can i ask this for wasting my time.

Comment: nDPI does a lot less detailed analysis than Wireshark - it's not a library for looking at every field of a packet, it's a library for *quickly* recognizing protocols; take a look at the files in the `src/lib/protocols` directory of the nDPI source. If you want to look at packet details, you need to look elsewhere (for example, look at Wireshark and adding support for the protocols you need).  Remember, "deep" is a marketing term, and doesn't necessarily imply "detailed" (or anything other than "protocols above the transport layer").

Comment: If what you want to do is *classify* packets - for example, if all you care about Skype is "this is Skype" and "this packet is part of this particular Skype flow" - then what you'd want to do would be to, for example, write your own libpcap code to capture packets and then pass the raw packet data to a routine such as nDPI's `ndpi_detection_process_packet()`, or, if you *really* want to combine it with tcpdump, call a routine such as `ndpi_detection_process_packet()` somewhere in the tcpdump per-packet code path and do something useful with the results.

Comment: Thankyou harris for your kind response.ya now i got a clear idea.does you have any sample code for do that.i need a sample to do that .

Comment: It's not a *simple* example, but look at `ndpiReader.c` in the `example` directory of the nDPI source code.

Comment: ya i looked already.but i didn't get any idea.so that i raised a query here